# Flutter : VideoPlayer carshing

Tags: flutter, dart, crash, video-player

I'm trying to add video_player plugin to show videos in my project but the project is crashing and show this on the console

> [ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(43)]
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error during attachToGLContext (see logcat
> for details) E/flutter (15242):   at
> android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.attachToGLContext(SurfaceTexture.java:286)
> E/flutter (15242): F/flutter (15242):
> [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(1062)]
> Check failed: CheckException(env). F/libc    (15242): Fatal signal 6
> (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 15334 (1.raster)

this is the method which i use

```
VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'http://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

@override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

Container(
                    height: 200,
                    child: Scaffold(
                      body: Center(
                        child: _controller.value.initialized
                            ? AspectRatio(
                                aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                              )
                            : Container(),
                      ),
                      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _controller.value.isPlaying
                                ? _controller.pause()
                                : _controller.play();
                          });
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                          _controller.value.isPlaying
                              ? Icons.pause
                              : Icons.play_arrow,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),),
```

so can anyone tell me what the wrong !!!

Comment: I was facing the same issue, hope this helps (worked for me) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65189624/flutter-app-crashes-for-any-video-before-it-even-starts-playing-on-my-android-ph